# substring check assistance with android

Tags: android, substring

Can someone please help me with some code I have it is supposed to check that the string being passed is of 2 string and 3 ints which works fine, but if the 1 int is a zero it doesn't work

so if it was CM044 it won't work, CM450 will work can someone please help.

```
public boolean checkModule(String Module) {

    if(Module.length() == 5){
      boolean hasString = false;
      boolean hasInt = false;
      String letters = Module.substring(0, 2);
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(letters);
      if (m.matches()) {
        hasString = true;
      }
      String numbers=Module.substring(2,5);
      try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
        String n = num + "";
        if (num >0 && n.length() == 3)
            hasInt = true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      if (hasInt && hasString) {
        return true;
      }
     }else{
      return false;
     }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If this is a school assignment, please add the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use regular expressions you should definitely stick with them and not vary in and out.

```
package com.examples;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        String[] testInputs = new String[] {"CM045", "CM450"};

        for(String input : testInputs) {
            System.out.println("The module " + input + " is " + (checkModule(input) ? "valid" : "invalid"));
        }
    }

    public boolean checkModule(String Module){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(Module.toUpperCase());
        return m.matches();
    }

}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. But I would modify the regex to: "[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}" since the number portion cannot start with 0.

Comment: I think his wording is hard to understand but to me it seems that he wants CM045 to be valid and his code, because of int parsing, is making it not valid as it drops the leading 0 and thus failing to appear as an int with a length of 3.

Comment: Additionally my comment on regular expressions should probably come with reasoning. Regular expressions are powerful but they do have a cost of creating and executing the engine. Because of this it would be wise to get all of the checks done in one run instead of running an expression then later doing more checks that the expression could have done for you.

Answer (score 0):

if the String is "045" the Integer value is 45 and so the length of num can't be 3

Use this

```
if(num>=0) {
  hasInt = true;
}
```

and it has to work

Comment: I tried this one earlier as noticed the> but it still didn't work.